# Missing Ripple target devices in Visual Studio Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Running a blank app, which builds fine. In the standard toolbar, when I try to start debugging on Android, I do not see any options to target a Ripple device. I only see 1 option, which says "Start".

*I did select the cross-platform mobile development tools in setup, as mentioned here: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#choose

How can I get the Ripple devices to show up in the target list?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IvLV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several projects in your solution. Please set your cordova project as the startup project.

If your cordova project is already the startup project, please try the following steps:

1. Close all VS instances
2. Open this folder `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools` And you will see **CoreCon** folder.
3. rename **CoreCon** folder
4. Launch VS again.